# How to bring javascript variable to next page?

Tags: javascript, html

In my codes there are two buttons that changes an image.(All codes are written in one php file). How do i take the src of the image and store it into a javascript variable and transfer it to another page?

HTML

```
<button onclick="red()">red</button>
<button onclick="blue()">blue</button>
<img id="color" src="green.png" />
```

Javascript

```
function blue()
    {
    document.getElementById(color).src="blue.png";
    }

function red()
    {
    document.getElementById(color).src="red.png";
    }
```

Comment: You can use the jQuery Cookie plugin for this task: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: You should look at JavaScript [DOMStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: I used Domdocument to store the src in a php variable, but in the next page it displays the original src(green.png). For some reason it doesn't update, so im trying to do in javascript. Does the new src update if i use DOMdocument in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use JavaScript [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) API

Your current page:

```
function blue()
{
    document.getElementById(color).src="blue.png";
    localStorage.setItem('new_image', 'blue.png');        //Add this
}

function red()
{
    document.getElementById(color).src="red.png";
    localStorage.setItem('new_image', 'red.png');       //Add this
}
```

On next page you can get your value with following:

```
<script>
var whatImage = localStorage.getItem('new_image');
alert(whatImage);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you need a jquery library or anything linked for this to work?

Comment: @user3121403 No this is native to JavaScript language.

Answer (score 2):

In the first page add this code:

```
document.cookie = "image_src=" + src_of_the_image +";";
```

In the second page, you retrieve this way:

```
var tmp = document.cookie;
var name_len = "image_src=".length;
var prev_img_src = tmp.substring(name_len);
```

Note that this works when there is a single cookie. To have a more concrete view on how to store & retrieve multiple cookies, check [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username).

Answer (score 1):

The other way you have is to use `LocalStorage`:

```
function blue(){
    localStorage.setItem("imagePath", "blue.png");
    document.getElementById(color).src="blue.png";
}

function red(){
    localStorage.setItem("imagePath", "red.png")
    document.getElementById(color).src="red.png";
}
```

then in the other page find the image you want to change and:

```
img.src = localStorage.getItem("imagePath");
```